# Create a subdirectory on a server?

Tags: c#, hosting

I am developing an application in c# which prompts the user for a directory name and then the directory is created on a server where I plan to host the websites. How can this be done ? What do I need to look into ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you need to look into:

1) how to create a directory in C#

2) how to best grant permissions to the user account running the web application to perform file system operations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the folder
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

But you'll need to make sure you have write permissions on the server, so you may want to look into *impersonation*.